# Flutter: Android system tooltip background color

Tags: android, flutter, tooltip

Does anyone know how to change android **system tooltip**(on longpress TextField) background color ? tried to change with [TooltipTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TooltipTheme-class.html) , canvasColor,popUpMenu.color didn't help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can define the color as part of the `decoration` property as follows:

```
Tooltip(
      message: 'I am a Tooltip',
      child: const Text('Tap this text and hold down to show a tooltip.'),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        // Set your color here
        color: Colors.white
      ),
      height: 50,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    ),
```

Comment: I was talking about SYSTEM tooltip on TextField (where you can select all, copy or paste) not flutter's tooltip widget, anyways thanks for willing to help